# GARCH simulation in-sample results make no sense

Tags: simulation, likelihood, aic, garch, volatility-forecasting

Idea is to simulate two different garch models with different parameters and later to take loglikelihood of separate models as well as of the concatenation.

I wanted to make working example of the plot and fit of this
https://youtu.be/7K0V2xBjFVM?t=98

Now since arch package makes constraint $\alpha+\beta<=1$ I can't get the same result but I hoped to get at least AIC/BIC and loglikelihood of mixed_garch being a lot smaller than of any separate model. Instead it seems like mixed_garch fitted performs better than high_vol garch.

This is my code

```
def simulate_GARCH(n, omega, alpha, beta):
    np.random.seed(7)
    epsilon = np.random.normal(size=n)
    residuals = np.zeros_like(epsilon)
    variance = np.zeros_like(epsilon)
    
    for t in range(1, n):
        variance[t] = omega + alpha * residuals[t-1]**2 + beta * variance[t-1]
        residuals[t] = np.sqrt(variance[t]) * epsilon[t]    
    
    return residuals, variance

garch_low_vol_residuals, garch_low_vol_variance = simulate_GARCH(n=300, omega = 0.005, alpha = 0.1, beta = 0.8)
garch_high_vol_residuals, garch_high_vol_variance = simulate_GARCH(n=300,omega = 0.025, alpha = 0.1, beta = 0.8)

arr = np.concatenate((garch_low_vol_residuals, garch_high_vol_residuals))

mixed_garch = arch_model(arr, p=1, q=1, mean='constant', vol='GARCH', dist='normal')
mixed_garch_result = mixed_garch.fit(disp='off')
mixed_garch_result.summary()

low_vol_garch = arch_model(garch_low_vol_residuals, p=1, q=1, mean='constant', vol='GARCH', dist='normal')
low_vol_garch_result = low_vol_garch.fit(disp='off')
low_vol_garch_result.summary()

high_vol_garch = arch_model(garch_high_vol_residuals, p=1, q=1, mean='constant', vol='GARCH', dist='normal')
high_vol_garch_result = high_vol_garch.fit(disp='off')
high_vol_garch_result.summary()
```

Comment: And your question is?..

Comment: How is it possible that model generated by parameters has worse likelihood than model mixed out of two separate models?

Comment: But you say *it seems like mixed_garch fitted performs better than high_vol garch*. Is that not contradictory?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my last comment was wrong. I meant opposite. Mixed garch has LL=-131, low_vol garch has LL=58 and high_vol garch has LL=-183.